# how to turn a string formula in a cell into a real formula in VBA code

Tags: vba, string, variables, formula, cell

I have defined a variable in VBA code, say, Myvar and I have a formula in a cell related to it,  say, 0.3*Myvar. How I can return the value of 0.3*Myvar in another cell?

For example, in cell A1 I have 0.3*Myvar. the code below will return 0.3*Myvar in cell B2, while I want to return 0.9.

```
sub string_value()
    Myvar=3
    cells(2,2)=cells(1,1)
end sub
```

Comment: Try `Dim Myvar as Long` and then `cells(2,2).value = cells(1,1).value * Myvar`

Comment: @FaneDuru showed you a way to insert value. If you would like to insert formula, then try this: `cells(2,2).Formula = cells(1,1).Address * Myvar`

Comment: @Maciej Los: with an equal in front of it... `"=" & cells(1, )....`:)

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work. Actually I have an array of equations which their variables are defined in VBA code. I need that VBA code interpret the equations as equation and not string.